# How does python 2 and 3 deal with inheritance differently?

Tags: python

Why is the code output is different in python 2 and python 3?

```
class A:
    def m(self):
        print("m of A called")

class B(A):
    pass

class C(A):
    def m(self):
        print("m of C called")

class D(B,C):
    pass

x = D()
x.m()
```

Actual Output:

```
$ python  diamond1.py     //python 2 used for the code 
m of A called

$ python3 diamond1.py     //python 3 used for the code
m of C called
```

Can somebody tell how(the order of calling) are the methods (method m) being called and why and what is the difference in their implementation in python 2 and python 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is specific to Python 2 and has to do with old-style vs new-style classes (Python 3 only has the latter).  In particular, the two styles of classes use different method resolution orders.

For more information, see https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass

If you change the code like so:

```
class A(object):
```

you'll get consistent behaviour as it'll make everything a new-style class.

Old-style classes only exist for compatibility with Python 2.1 and earlier (we're talking the year 2001).